# Defining a Torch Class in R package "torch"

Tags: r, pytorch, reticulate

this post is related to my earlier [How to define a Python Class which uses R code, but called from rTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416903/how-to-define-a-python-class-which-uses-r-code-but-called-from-rtorch) .

I came across the `torch` package in R (https://torch.mlverse.org/docs/index.html) which allows to Define a DataSet class definition. Yet, I also need to be able to define a model class like `class MyModelClass(torch.nn.Module)` in Python. Is this possible in the torch package in R?

When I tried to do it with `reticulate` it did not work - there were conflicts like

```
  ImportError: /User/homes/mreichstein/miniconda3/envs/r-torch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so: undefined symbol: _ZTINSt6thread6_StateE
```

It also would not make much sense, since `torch` isn't wrapping Python.

But it is loosing at lot of flexibility, which rTorch has (but see my problem in the upper post).
Thanks for any help!
Markus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that directly using R's `torch` package which seems quite comprehensive at least for the basic tasks.

### Neural networks

[Here](https://torch.mlverse.org/docs/articles/getting-started/nn.html) is an example of how to create `nn.Sequential` like this:

```
library(torch)

model <- nn_sequential(
    nn_linear(D_in, H),
    nn_relu(),
    nn_linear(H, D_out)
)
```

Below is a custom `nn_module` (a.k.a. `torch.nn.Module`) which is a simple dense (`torch.nn.Linear`) layer ([source](https://torch.mlverse.org/docs/articles/examples/basic-nn-module.html)):

```
library(torch)

# creates example tensors. x requires_grad = TRUE tells that 
# we are going to take derivatives over it.
dense <- nn_module(
  clasname = "dense",
  # the initialize function tuns whenever we instantiate the model
  initialize = function(in_features, out_features) {
    
    # just for you to see when this function is called
    cat("Calling initialize!") 
    
    # we use nn_parameter to indicate that those tensors are special
    # and should be treated as parameters by `nn_module`.
    self$w <- nn_parameter(torch_randn(in_features, out_features))
    self$b <- nn_parameter(torch_zeros(out_features))
    
  },
  # this function is called whenever we call our model on input.
  forward = function(x) {
    cat("Calling forward!")
    torch_mm(x, self$w) + self$b
  }
)

model <- dense(3, 1)
```

Another example, using `torch.nn.Linear` layers to create a neural network this time ([source](https://torch.mlverse.org/docs/articles/getting-started/custom-nn.html)):

```
two_layer_net <- nn_module(
   "two_layer_net",
   initialize = function(D_in, H, D_out) {
      self$linear1 <- nn_linear(D_in, H)
      self$linear2 <- nn_linear(H, D_out)
   },
   forward = function(x) {
      x %>% 
         self$linear1() %>% 
         nnf_relu() %>% 
         self$linear2()
   }
)
```

Also there are other resources like [here](https://torch.mlverse.org/docs/articles/getting-started/control-flow-and-weight-sharing.html) (using flow control and weight sharing).

### Other

Looking at [the reference](https://torch.mlverse.org/docs/reference/index.html#section-neural-network-modules) it seems most of the layers are already provided (didn't notice transformer layers at a quick glance, but this is minor).

As far as I can tell basic blocks for neural networks, their training etc. are in-place (even JIT so sharing between languages should be possible).

Comment: Great - how could I be so blind.... . Yet, is it true, that no "general" Python Class can be generated, e.g. from another super class, if not implemented in torch? Say e.g. an EarlyStopping class or so.

Comment: @MR_MP-BGC I'm not sure what you mean in this case. There is no EarlyStopping in PyTorch (there is in PyTorch Lightning or a-like, which does not exist for R). If you ask whether we can use, we would need `reticulate` and it probably wouldn't work (as it requires `LightningModule` which is based on `nn.Module`). If you ask whether we can code that, yeah, sure, why not? It's just a control flow checking validation loss, similar to what is shared [here](https://torch.mlverse.org/docs/articles/getting-started/control-flow-and-weight-sharing.html).

Comment: @MR_MPI-BGC Also you can code anything you can code in Python (it might be easier or harder, faster or slower) as both languages are Turing complete.

Comment: Thanks, yes in can code that also in R (I did....), but I was thinking to use as much of the Pytorch ecosystem in Python as possible (e.g. Lightning, but possibly also other classes ==> leveraging all the parallelization etc. (?) ), and as much of R as possible for data prep and plotting. Using Python classes directly and `reticulate` also helps sharing with colleagues working in Python.... There are always tradeoffs....

Comment: You can do preprocessing and cleaning in R, save the data, load them with Python and train neural network on them. No need for any tradeoffs.